# Access VBA replace() throws strange runtime error

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS Access 2010 VB Code I am trying to replace certain fractions of a string by something else using the replace() function.
E.g.

```
Original = "ACBD"
Result = replace(Original, "C", "x")
```

expecting to have "ABxD" as Result.

However all I get is a runtime error '438' stating that the "object does not support the property or method".

I know there is also a .replace method for TextRange2 objects but why would Access VB mix that up?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including variable declarations. I can't replicate this behaviour. You can try use `VBA.Replace` instead of `replace`. If that works, you've defined a function called replace somewhere/

Comment: I found the reason: The code is from a form where I have an action button named "Replace" :-( VBA.replace does the job. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: There's a reason to use Hungarian notation for your UI objects (e.g. `cmdReplace`).